Lost on how to separate columns
I want to separate a column of my dataset into different columns. However, the problem is that the column of interest is dirty and does not split the I want. This is the column I have.



notified_amount
nomenclature_of_loans




7000
6.64% GS 2029


8000
7.46%GS 2017 (1)


25000
12.25   % GS, 2010 (1) (12)



I have tried the following code:
govt_1 |> 
    separate_wider_delim(nomenclature_of_loans, delim = " ", names = c("rate", "type", "year"),
                         too_few = "align_end", too_many = "merge")

I tried the separate_wider_delim function to extract the year from the nomenclature_of_loans column. Though I am successful in doing so for quite some rows, dirty rows are preventing me from extracting year for all the rows and I am stuck.
Now I don't care about the rate and type columns. I want to successfully separate the year from the nomenclature_of_loans column. While the first column perfectly splits, I am having problems with the second and third type. Mind you, my dataset has 2,800 rows. And around 350 rows are throwing a similar problem. I am stuck and unsure on how to proceed.
Ideally, this is the output I want



notified_amount
rate
year




7000
6.64%
2029


8000
7.46%
2017


25000
12.25%
2010



But, I am okay with extracting just the year alone too.
If you have any information on how to pre-clean the data before splitting or how to further clean the after splitting the data, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Using str_extract() from the stringr library, we can try:
govt_1$rate <- str_extract(govt_1$nomenclature_of_loans, "^\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?\\s*%")
govt_1$year <- str_extract(govt_1$nomenclature_of_loans, "\\b\\d{4}\\b")


Hi! Thank you so much for the code. It works!. But I have a couple of clarification questions. in govt_1$rate , you have used \\s*%. Now I understand \ is used as an escape character for \\%, but I'm unable to get why s* was used.
Second, I know \b is used for boundary identification, but I'm unsure of the usage here.
I have tried to work it out myself, but got stuck at the above two instances! Could you please provide some explanation about those? Thank you so much in advance!


There is no need to escape % in a regular expression and 2) I used \\s*% in my answer because some of your input data had 12.25 %, with a space before the %.  The \\s* is optional whitespace.


You probably need to use regular expressions  to separate the rate and year.  These can be tricky, and probably what I suggest here will get you started but not quite all of the way.  If you get stuck with more confounding strings in your nomenclature column, either add them to your question or start a new question.  But here's a start.
If you start with the tibble
library(tidyverse)

govt_1 <- tibble(nomenclature_of_loans = c("6.64% GS 2029", "7.46%GS 2017 (1)", "12.25   % GS, 2010 (1) (12)"))

then to pull out the year, you could use
govt_1 |> 
    mutate(yr = str_extract(nomenclature_of_loans, "20[0-9]{2}"))

assuming that your years are in the current century and that the messy strings around them don't look like dates too.
To get the percentage and the year, you could try
govt_1 |> 
    mutate(x = str_match(nomenclature_of_loans, "(\\d+?\\.\\d+\\%).+?(20[0-9]{2})"),
           rate = x[,2],
           year = x[,3])

The x column is actually a column of tibbles.  Those can be confusing to work with so I showed you how to extract the rate and column from them.
Creating regular expressions can feel like a superpower and a curse at the same time.  The one above looks for a digit \\d that might be repeated + but also might not be there at all ?.  To look for a decimal point, you must escape it \\.  The percentage sign also should be escaped \\%.  The bit for the percentage is wrapped in round parentheses because it will be the first capture group.  The year is in the second capture group.  Between them I use an unescaped period to represent any character that might appear there.  I use the +? after the period to catch as much or little garbage as there might be.

Thank you so much for the detailed explanation /\

Instead of using separate_wider_delim you can use separate_wider_regex to separate on patterns or regular expressions similar to the other answers using str_xxx but requires to be more explicit about the parts of the string that you want to discard:
govt_1 <- data.frame(
  notified_amount = c(7000L, 8000L, 25000L),
  nomenclature_of_loans = c(
    "6.64% GS 2029",
    "7.46%GS 2017 (1)", "12.25 % GS, 2010 (1) (12)"
  )
)

library(tidyr)

govt_1 |>
  separate_wider_regex(
    nomenclature_of_loans,
    patterns = c(
      rate = "^\\d+\\.\\d+\\s?%",
      ".*?",
      year = "\\d{4}",
      ".*$"
    )
  ) |>
  dplyr::mutate(rate = gsub("\\s%", "%", rate))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   notified_amount rate   year 
#>             <int> <chr>  <chr>
#> 1            7000 6.64%  2029 
#> 2            8000 7.46%  2017 
#> 3           25000 12.25% 2010


1) tidyverse Separate the fields by percent (%) and then extract the first number from each using parse_number.  No regular expressions are used.
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(tidyr)

govt_1 %>%
  separate_wider_delim (nomenclature_of_loans, 
    names = c("rate", "year"), delim = "%") %>%
  mutate(across(rate:year, parse_number))

giving
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  notified_amount  rate  year
            <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1            7000  6.64  2029
2            8000  7.46  2017
3           25000 12.2   2010

2) strcapture Using only base R we can use strcapture with the indicated regular expression.  The matches to the capture groups in the regular expression will be assigned to the names and types in proto.
pat <- "(\\d+.\\d+)\\D+(\\d{4})"
proto <- list(rate = numeric(0), year = numeric(0))
with(govt_1, 
  data.frame(notified_amount, strcapture(pat, nomenclature_of_loans, proto)))

giving
  notified_amount  rate year
1            7000  6.64 2029
2            8000  7.46 2017
3           25000 12.25 2010

3) read.table Again using only base R we can split the field into two using read.table and then fix up year.  The only regular expression used is \D which matches any non-digit.
govt_1 |>
  with(data.frame(
    notified_amount,
    read.table(text = nomenclature_of_loans, sep = "%", comment.char = "(",
      col.names = c("rate", "year"))) |>
  transform(year = as.numeric(trimws(year, whitespace = "\\D"))))

giving
  notified_amount  rate year
1            7000  6.64 2029
2            8000  7.46 2017
3           25000 12.25 2010

Note
The input in reproducible form
govt_1  <- data.frame(
  notified_amount = c(7000L, 8000L, 25000L),
  nomenclature_of_loans = c("6.64% GS 2029", "7.46%GS 2017 (1)", "12.25 % GS, 2010 (1) (12)")
)

